# How to get a text character based on a number position in the alphabet in a QGIS expression

Tags: qgis, expression

This seems very simple but I can't find a function that will take a number between 1 and 26 and return the right letter.
1=A
2=B
3=C
...
Z=26

Comment: The SQL function is `CHR()`, though it takes a decimal value of the ASCII code, so you need to add 64 to obtain the digit (`CHR(64+n)`).

Comment: You have the standard **CHAR()** function under String

Comment: CHAR() works fine, I should have spotted that.

Comment: But `CHAR(65)` -> `A`, so for `1 = A` it's `CHAR(1 + 64)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this QGIS expression: replace the number `1` at the second last line with any number from 1 to 26 to get the corresponding letter - if you set it to `5`, it will return `E`:

```
map_get(
    hstore_to_map( 
        array_to_string (
            array_foreach (
                generate_series (1,26),
                to_string (
                    @element || '=>' || char (@element+64)
                )
            )
        )
    ),1
)
```

You could use a custom variable instead of the number to be more flexible and get the current value of the variable from somewhere else.

Comment: More simply : `array_get(array_foreach(generate_series(1 + 63, 26 + 63), char(@element)), 1)` or even `with_variable('num_letter', 1, char(@num_letter + 64))` or `char(1 + 64)`.

Comment: CHR(64+n) as per @vince's comment works fine for what I need

Comment: @J. Monticolo: indeed, you're right. I started playing around with `map` functions and overlooked the easier way to do it.